# android/phonegap Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am getting the below exception when i try to invoke a javascript call from an android application that uses PhoneGap.

Stacktrack error:

```
06-01 13:58:40.225: D/CordovaLog(1197): Uncaught ReferenceError: recieve is not defined
06-01 13:58:40.225: E/Web Console(1197): Uncaught ReferenceError: recieve is not defined at null:1
```

here is my .jp file

```
    <!-- register -->

        function register(toggle){
        var e = toggle;
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        console.info(toggle);
        console.info(value);
            if (value == "on"){
                window.WRAPPER.register();
            }else if(value == "off"){
                window.WRAPPER.deregister();
            }

        }


  <!-- send  -->

        function send(message){
            console.info('sending message');
            console.info(message);
            window.WRAPPER.send(message);
        }


    <!-- recieve -->

        function recieve(msg){
            console.info('recieving message');
            console.info(msg);
            document.getElementById("textarea1").innerHTML = msg;
        }
```

Here is my android code that creates a javascript:functionName() string and loads it to the webView

```
String text = "hello";

String javaScript = "javascript:recieve(\'"+text+"\')";

Log.d("TAG", javaScript);

loadUrl(javaScript);
```

Comment: Does your `.js` file actually have those `<script>` tags in it? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: i removed it and it managed to fix it. however it says it cannot identify the javascript i am calling. updating post to reflect this. the error is this 06-01 13:58:40.225: D/CordovaLog(1197): Uncaught ReferenceError: recieve is not defined
06-01 13:58:40.225: E/Web Console(1197): Uncaught ReferenceError: recieve is not defined at null:1

Comment: Why do you call Javascript from your native code like that? First, I think, that the loadURL command in the Java code should be provided with an actual url, not an string. I don't get the point why you want to handle Code which you receive in the javascript file in your native code. I assume that you use phonegap. So where is this native code called? Please provide further information, than we can might help you, but it looks a little bit ugly what you are doing there ;-)

Comment: Is there any other way to call a javascript from native code? what information do you need? the native code is on a standard android activity where it listens out for some callback and updates the HTML content of an even that has occured.

Comment: Anyone have any other suggestions?